# How to synchronize access on OSGi configuration

Tags: java, osgi

I'm currently writing a service, that changes configurations provided by the ConfigurationAdmin.

Because the configuration behind a pid may be updated by a few other services, especially at start-up, I'm a bit worried about synchronization. It's because at the time, my service updates a configuration via Configuration#update() it expects that it is the same it got when it called ConfigurationAdmin#getConfiguration(String). But it could be possible that it was changed in the time between by another service - and I want to avoid that.

Any ideas?

EDIT: here's the usecase
What I want to do is to create a service that sets default configuration for a certain set of pid's. If such a pid has a configuration or someone sets it then I don't do anything with it:

1. I take a configuration from the configadmin
2. I take the properties of it
3. If there is nothing relevant set, I set the defaults and update the configuration.

I'm just afraid that something happens in that order but asynchronously:

1. (Thread 1). I get the empty configuration, and see its empty and set the defaults
2. (Thread 2) Update configuration with a properties that don't need a default
3. (Thread 1) Update and Overwrite config by Thread 1

Therefore I just want to assure, that nobody updates the configuration while I check it for being empty and then set the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not have multiple parties trying to manage the same configurations. It sounds like you really need multiple configurations, each party managing one.

Comment: I added a usecase that explains why I want to do this.

Comment: But you still have multiple parties trying to manage a single configuration. That is the bad design I was saying you need to avoid. Only a single "management agent" should be responsible for managing the configuration for a pid.